# PostgreSQL COLLATE and Character Type - Values to use in a RDS Service hosted in Australia

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, character-encoding, collation, amazon-aurora

We are using Aurora RDS PostgreSQL database in AWS Sydney (ap-southeast-2)

The application requires an UTF-8 encoding.

What should the Collation and character types be?

```
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
```

Does using **en_US.UTF-8** instead of *en_AU.UTF-8* have any impact?

I am unable to come to a conclusion based on my searches so far.

The default value when I work with the AWS console (for RDS) is en_US. Based on this I am guessing that it should be good however would like to hear from experts on any potential issues/pitfalls here.

There are a few questions that talk about differences between C.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 but I can't see any queries/answers between en_US.UTF-8 and en_AU.UTF-8.

Some of the Q&As in this space that I tried to get some insights are listed here for quick reference:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46408/how-to-choose-a-collation-for-international-database

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240930/postgresql-difference-between-collations-c-and-c-utf-8

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211544/postgres-encoding-collation-and-ctype

**Note:** Cross posted this in [DBA Stack exchange.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271831/postgresql-collate-and-character-type-values-to-use-in-a-rds-service-hosted-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"en_US.UTF-8 instead of en_AU.UTF-8":- These are just UTF-8 Variants of 2 different locale. one would use en_AU.UTF-8 because they would want to use English-Australian as opposed to English-US, but both are using UTF-8 Encoding. The Only thing I can think of that would have small overhead would be automatic character conversion between server and client:- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/multibyte.html#id-1.6.10.5.7There is nothing different on collation and character types between Stock Postgres and Aurora Postgres.